# Given a probability over time, predict when an event will happen

Tags: probability

First of all, I'm asking this because I'm writing a game, so this is probably not a typical question in probability. However I'm new to game design so I don't even know what this would be called.

Suppose I have a certain event that should occur and the probability of that event happening (over a certain amount of time). For example, let's suppose the probability is 15% per day.

Is there a *single calculation* I can perform that will, along with an evenly distributed random number, predict *when* that event will occur?

Predict is probably not the best word to use here, since I'm not going for accuracy in a single prediction, only a realistic distribution, were it to be predicted over and over again with different random numbers.

Ideally it should not be limited to a certain temporal resolution. I.e. it should not be an even number of days, but should be a continuous function giving me a result right down to the second.

Comment: You should look into the Geometric distribution.

Comment: Just a side note: this question has nothing to do with game theory (which you mention in the first paragraph). Game theory deals with strategic decision making in (typically) multi-player settings. Your question is straight probability.

Comment: Fair enough. Changed it to game design to avoid confusion (and removed tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a random number uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$.

Then $T=\bigg\lfloor \dfrac{\log X}{\log 0.85 }\bigg\rfloor +1$ will have the integer distribution you seek, where $\lfloor y \rfloor$ means the floor or integer part of $y$.  It does not matter much what base logarithms you you so long as you are consistent.

You will find that about $15\%$ of the time this will give $T=1$, about $12.75\%$ this gives $T=2$ and so on.

If you want this as fractions of a day, then use $T= \dfrac{\log X}{\log 0.85 }$.

This will still give you $15\%$ probability of  $0 \lt T \le 1$, and $12.75\%$ probability of giving $1 \lt T \le 2$ and so on.

For the integer valued distribution this is the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  For the positive real valued distribution this is the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Comment: To be clear, he used .85 because .85=1-.15. If you want some probability other than .15 per day, modify accordingly.